# I want to add "favourite books or basket" in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to understand relationships on django and create a little project but I'm stuck.So basically I want to add a field (sort of basket) so that people can add their favourite items among many of them. But I can't implement it. What should I do inside my models? Thanks. Bye the way I want to turn this into RESTFUL.I'll appreciate if you give me any advice.
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    fav_product = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be ManytoMany relationship in my opinion. Product can has many users (many users can add the product to favourites) and user can has many products (user can add many products to favourites).